# error in coding in pygame

Tags: pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
screen=pygame.display.set_mode()
nin=pygame.image.load('/home/satyajit/Desktop/nincompoop0001.bmp')
screen.blit(nin,(50,100))
```

according to the code i should get  a screen with an image of nin on it . But I only get a black screen which doesnt go even though i press the exit button on it. how to get the image on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `pygame.display.flip()` whenever you want the screen to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

As well as calling `pygame.display.flip()` (or `pygame.display.update()` if it is a software based surface). you will also need to call pygame.init() at the start of your program and eventually call pygame.quit() to close down the window and do cleanup.

you code might then be

```
import pygame,time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode()
nin=pygame.image.load('/home/satyajit/Desktop/nincompoop0001.bmp')
screen.blit(nin,(50,100))
pygame.display.flip()
time.sleep(10)
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
screen=pygame.display.set_mode()
nin=pygame.image.load('nincompoop0001.bmp')
screen.blit(nin,(50,100))
```

Then, place the image in the same directory as your script.